# Посоветуйте хороший С++ профилировщик под Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Посоветуйте хороший С++ профилировщик под Ubuntu. Спасибо.

Comment: А gprof не спасёт отца русской демократии? Правда он не только под ubuntu, он в сюите gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартом для Linux является gprof.

```
gcc sample.c -pg -o sample && ./sample && gprof sample gmon.out
```

Также часто пользуют [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html). И еще есть [google-perftools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/).